# How to import JsonConvert in C# application?

Tags: c#, json.net

I created a C# library project. The project has this line in one class:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectList);
```

I'm getting error saying

> the name JsonConvert doesn't exist in the current context.

To fix that, I added `System.ServiceModel.Web.dll` to references but had no luck. How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 208, accepted):

`JsonConvert` is from the namespace `Newtonsoft.Json`, not `System.ServiceModel.Web`

Use `NuGet` to download the `package`

"Project" -> "Manage NuGet packages" -> "Search for "newtonsoft json". -> click "install".

Comment: is you are building a .NET Core WebApi or WebSite see my answer below

Comment: also, make sure 'using Newtonsoft.Json;' is there

Answer (score 54):

right click on the project and select `Manage NuGet Packages..`
In that select `Json.NET` and install

After installation,

use the following namespace

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

then use the following to deserialize

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject
```

Comment: For .net core you dont need to install newtonsoft - see my answerbelow

Answer (score 19):

Install it using NuGet:

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

<sub>Posting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784697/how-to-import-jsonconvert-in-c-sharp-application#comment51182542_18784702) as an answer.</sub>

Comment: For .net core you dont need to install newtonsoft - see my answerbelow

Answer (score 15):

## Linux

[If you're using Linux and .NET Core, see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48018965/124486), you'll want to use

```
dotnet add package Newtonsoft.Json
```

And then add

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

to any classes needing that.

Comment: For .net core you dont need to install newtonsoft - see my answerbelow

Comment: (This also works on Windows with .NET Core and dotnet CLI)

Answer (score 8):

Or if you're using dotnet Core,

add to your .csproj file

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="9.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

And

```
dotnet restore
```

Comment: For .net core you dont need to install newtonsoft - see my answerbelow

Answer (score 4):

If you are **developing a .Net Core WebApi or WebSite you dont not need to install newtownsoft.json** to perform json serialization/deserealization

Just make sure that your controller method returns a `JsonResult` and call `return Json(<objectoToSerialize>);` like this example

```
namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/Accounts")]
    public class AccountsController : Controller
    {
        // GET: api/Transaction
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Get()
        {
            List<Account> lstAccounts;

            lstAccounts = AccountsFacade.GetAll();

            return Json(lstAccounts);
        }
    }
}
```

If you are developing a **.Net Framework WebApi or WebSite you need to use NuGet to download and install the `newtonsoft json` package**

"Project" -> "Manage NuGet packages" -> "Search for "newtonsoft json". -> click "install".

```
namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/Accounts")]
    public class AccountsController : Controller
    {
        // GET: api/Transaction
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Get()
        {
            List<Account> lstAccounts;

            lstAccounts = AccountsFacade.GetAll();

            //This line is different !! 
            return new JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstAccounts);
        }
    }
}
```

More details can be found here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 3):

Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Comment: For .net core you dont need to install newtonsoft - see my answerbelow

Answer (score 1):

Please give the below command:

```
dotnet add package Newtonsoft.Json
```

and then it works.

Answer (score 0):

After instaling the package you need to add the newtonsoft.json.dll into assemble path by runing the flowing command.

Before we can use our assembly, we have to add it to the global assembly cache (GAC). Open the Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt again (for Vista/Windows7/etc. open it as Administrator). And execute the following command.
gacutil /i d:\myMethodsForSSIS\myMethodsForSSIS\bin\Release\myMethodsForSSIS.dll

flow this link for more informATION
http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/05/referencing-custom-assembly-inside.html