# How to change file to retrieve data from Json?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

Don't know if my question is put well, but here is my problem:
I managed to get on my Generator.aspx page some Json values from ajax.aspx.cs page. Everything works fine. I tried to move the code from ajax.aspx.cs to Generator.aspx.cs page but doesn't work.

Here is my ajax.aspx.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Diagnostics;


//for JsonConvert. I installed Json.NET. info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784697/how-to-import-jsonconvert-in-c-sharp-application
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace PumpsCurrents
{
    public partial class ajax : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        Random random1 = new Random();
        double RandomDouble(double min, double max)
        {
            return (max - min) * random1.NextDouble() + min;
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Page.Controls.Clear();
            Random rand = new Random();

            int CPUloading = rand.Next(0, 100);
            int CPUcore = CPUloading - 30 < 0 ? 0 : rand.Next(0, CPUloading - 30);
            int Disk = rand.Next(56, 1024);

            Response.Write("{\"cpu\":" + CPUloading + ", \"core\":" + CPUcore + ", \"disk\":" + Disk + "}");

            this.Response.Clear();
            this.Response.ClearHeaders();
            try
            {
                var method = this.Page.RouteData.Values["meth"] as string;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(method))
                {
                    method = this.Page.Request.QueryString["meth"];
                }
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(method))
                {
                    method = this.Page.Request.Form["meth"];
                }
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(method))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Method was not specified");
                }


                //START Random Value for Generator:


                if (method == "rnd7")
                {

                   this.Page.Response.ContentType = "application/json7";                    

                    //Functia RandomDouble(min,max) e declarata la inceputul programului 
                    //random pt curenti
                   double nr7 = RandomDouble(1,100); // creates a number between 1 and 99   
                   double nr8 = RandomDouble(1, 100); // creates a number between 1 and 99
                   double nr9 = RandomDouble(1, 100); // creates a number between 1 and 99
                   double nr10 = RandomDouble(1, 100);  // creates a number between 1 and 99

                    //random pt tensiune
                   double nr11 = RandomDouble(1, 100); // creates a number between 1 and 99
                   double nr12 = RandomDouble(1, 100); // creates a number between 1 and 99
                   double nr13 = RandomDouble(1, 100); // creates a number between 1 and 99
                   double nr14 = RandomDouble(1, 100); // creates a number between 1 and 99
                   double nr15 = RandomDouble(1, 100); // creates a number between 1 and 99

                    //random pt presiune
                   double nr16 = RandomDouble(1, 100); // creates a number between 1 and 99
                   double nr17 = RandomDouble(1, 100); // creates a number between 1 and 99
                   double nr18 = RandomDouble(1, 100); // creates a number between 1 and 99
                   double nr19 = RandomDouble(1, 100); // creates a number between 1 and 99
                   double nr20 = RandomDouble(1, 100); // creates a number between 1 and 99
                   double nr21 = RandomDouble(0, 1); // creates a number between 1 and 99

                   var str7 = "{\"val7\":" + nr7.ToString() + ",\"val8\":" + nr8.ToString() + ",\"val9\":" + nr9.ToString() + ",\"val10\":" + nr10.ToString() + ",\"val11\":" + nr11.ToString() +
                        ",\"val12\":" + nr12.ToString() + ",\"val13\":" + nr13.ToString() + ",\"val14\":" + nr14.ToString() + ",\"val15\":" + nr15.ToString() +
                        ",\"val16\":" + nr16.ToString() + ",\"val17\":" + nr17.ToString() + ",\"val18\":" + nr18.ToString() + ",\"val19\":" + nr19.ToString() + ",\"val20\":" + nr20.ToString() + ",\"val21\":" + nr21.ToString() +
         "}";
                    var json7 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(str7);
                    this.Page.Response.Write(json7);
                }

                //END Random Value for Generator



                this.Response.Flush();
                if (this.Response.SuppressContent)
                {
                    this.Response.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //if (ex is AuthenticationException)
                //{
                //    this.State.SignOut();
                //}
                this.Response.Clear();
                this.Response.ClearHeaders();
                this.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
                this.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                this.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                this.Response.Write(ex.Message);
                this.Response.End();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

And then I call the json in Generator.aspx page like:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Generator.aspx.cs" Inherits="PumpsCurrents.Generator" %>
//...
 function test1() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: ('ajax.aspx?meth=') + "rnd7",
                contentType: 'application/json7; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data7, textStatus7, jqXHR7) {

                   // Bring data from C# using JSON  

                    //current
                    var obj7 = jQuery.parseJSON(data7);
                    var obj8 = jQuery.parseJSON(data7);
                    var obj9 = jQuery.parseJSON(data7);
                    var obj10 = jQuery.parseJSON(data7);

                    //voltage
                    var obj11 = jQuery.parseJSON(data7);
                    var obj12 = jQuery.parseJSON(data7);
                    var obj13 = jQuery.parseJSON(data7);
                    var obj14 = jQuery.parseJSON(data7);
                    var obj15 = jQuery.parseJSON(data7);

                    //pressure
                    var obj16 = jQuery.parseJSON(data7);
                    var obj17 = jQuery.parseJSON(data7);
                    var obj18 = jQuery.parseJSON(data7);
                    var obj19 = jQuery.parseJSON(data7);
                    var obj20 = jQuery.parseJSON(data7);
                    var obj21 = jQuery.parseJSON(data7);

                    //current
                    $('#nr7').html(obj7.val7);
                    $('#nr8').html(obj8.val8);
                    $('#nr9').html(obj9.val9);
                    $('#nr10').html(obj10.val10);

                    //voltage
                    $('#nr11').html(obj11.val11);
                    $('#nr12').html(obj12.val12);
                    $('#nr13').html(obj13.val13);
                    $('#nr14').html(obj14.val14);
                    $('#nr15').html(obj15.val15);

                    //pressure
                    $('#nr16').html(obj16.val16);
                    $('#nr17').html(obj17.val17);
                    $('#nr18').html(obj18.val18);
                    $('#nr19').html(obj19.val19);
                    $('#nr20').html(obj20.val20);
                    $('#nr21').html(obj21.val21);

                    //current
                    t7 = obj7.val7;
                    t8 = obj8.val8;
                    t9 = obj9.val9;
                    t10 = obj10.val10; 

                    //voltage
                    t11 = obj11.val11;
                    t12 = obj12.val12;
                    t13 = obj13.val13;
                    t14 = obj14.val14;
                    t15 = obj15.val15;

                    //pressure
                    t16 = obj16.val16;
                    t17 = obj17.val17;
                    t18 = obj18.val18;
                    t19 = obj19.val19;
                    t20 = obj20.val20;
                    t21 = obj21.val21;


                },
                error: function (jqXHR7, textStatus7, errorThrown) {
                    window.alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });

        }

        setInterval(test1, 3000);
//+other methods...
```

If I put the same code from ajax.aspx.cs to Generator.aspx.cs page, and in my Generator.aspx, instead of `url: ('ajax.aspx?meth=') + "rnd7",` I put `url: ('Generator.aspx?meth=') + "rnd7",` it throws me on my web page "Method was not specified". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think you have to use another method for this operation rather than Page_Load()

Comment: You mean that I should rename the Page_Load() method from Generator.aspx.cs page? Or what do ypu mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call jquery ajax, then there are other good ways to do it .i.e (using Webservice, or generic handler).
Instead of sending data via QueryString, send it by JSON, list format

Follow this simple steps (Webservice)

1. Add new WebService.asmx : Right click on project solution --> Add New Item --> Select Webservice.aspx
2. Now create a webmethod in it.
3. Call this webmethod from jquery ajax call.

---

Follow this simple steps (Webservice)

1. Add new WebService.asmx : Right click on project solution --> Add New Item --> Select Generic Handler
2. Now write code logic inside it
3. Call jquery ajax with URL as Generic Handler PATH.

Instead of

```
var method = this.Page.RouteData.Values["meth"] as string;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(method))
                {
                    method = this.Page.Request.QueryString["meth"];
                }
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(method))
                {
                    method = this.Page.Request.Form["meth"];
                }
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(method))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Method was not specified");
                }
```

it should be

```
var method = this.Page.RouteData.Values["meth"] as string;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(method))
                {
                    method = this.Page.Request.QueryString["meth"];
                }
               else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(method))
                {
                    method = this.Page.Request.Form["meth"];
                }
              else  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(method))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Method was not specified");
                }
```

As you are getting error "Method was not specified", this mean if fall in last if condition

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm going to dig in this direction you pointed me. Gonna come back if I'll have questions.