# How to split this string into Dictionary<string,string>?

Tags: c#, .net, string, dictionary, split

I have the following string:

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2,some other part of value2"}
```

I can use the following long syntax to split this:

```
var s = someString.Split(new[] {"\",\""}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var firstEntryValue = s[0].Split(':')[1];
var secondEntryValue = s[1].Split(':')[1];
```

Since this string is basically a `Dictionary<string,string>`, how can I pull the whole thing into that type in basically one line?

I've seen something like this:

```
var s = someString.Split(new[] {"\",\""}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .Select(p => p.Split(':'))
  .ToDictionary(split => split[0], split => split[1]);
```

But it throws and index out of bounds error. Is there some similar syntax that will work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the string follows JSON format, splitting it is not a good option - precisely because of the issues that you mention.

You can use [`JsonConvert`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18784697/335858) instead:

```
var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(inputString);
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that he'll need the JSON.NET nuget package to use JsonConvert