# How do I download a package from the command line with .NET Core from nuget?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core, .net-core-2.0

Microsoft packages [.NET Core on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-install) for Ubuntu. I'm currently using that. I now want to install [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) which instructs me to use the [Package Manager console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-console) and run,

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

I'm wondering how I do that Linux. I see that there is a [Nuget CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-install), but it doesn't seem like that's available on .NET Core. [Moreover the docs say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/install-nuget#nuget-cli)

> On Mac and Linux, install Mono 4.4.2 or later.

How do I simply install a package on Linux? What's the .NET equivalent of npm/cpan/pip/gem?

When I run `dotnet nuget`, the `install` command seems to be missing.

```
NuGet Command Line 4.3.0.5

Usage: dotnet nuget [options] [command]

Options:
  -h|--help                   Show help information
  --version                   Show version information
  -v|--verbosity <verbosity>  The verbosity of logging to use. Allowed values: Debug, Verbose, Information, Minimal, Warning, Error.

Commands:
  delete  Deletes a package from the server.
  locals  Clears or lists local NuGet resources such as http requests cache, packages cache or machine-wide global packages folder.
  push    Pushes a package to the server and publishes it.

Use "dotnet nuget [command] --help" for more information about a command.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`dotnet add package --help`

`dotnet add package Newtonsoft.Json`

Please refer to the github page https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/core/tools/dotnet-add-package.md for more details.

Comment: Beautiful *"Add reference to the project."* apparently means download and install from a remote repository.. `npm install`, `cpanm --install` `pip install` `gem install`. Microsoft.. *"add reference to the project."*

Comment: `notepad yourproject.csproj`. Ow, and don't forget Ctrl-S when you are done !